# Use 2 jars compiled on different JDK in one application

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, java-6

Is it OK to use 2 jars (Jar1 is built on 1.6JDK, and Jar2 on 1.8JDK) in an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is OK, as long as the `JRE` running your application, is not older than JRE 1.8 in your case.